# Using CASE WHEN with an unknown number of categories

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table like this

```
Col1  Col2

A     0.1

B     2.4

B     2.1

C     5.0

...   ...
```

and that I want to obtain this other table

```
ColA  ColB  ColC

0.1   0     0

0     2.4   0

0     2.1   0

0     0     5.0

...   ...   ...
```

To create one single column I can use a `CASE WHEN` as

`SELECT CASE WHEN Col1 = 'A' THEN Col2 ELSE 0 END AS ColA FROM TABLE`

But I don't know a priori how many different categories I have in Col1 and there can be many of them. How could I obtain this result with BigQuery?

Comment: You are looking to 'PIVOT' the data so that you create columns out of rows

Comment: This is nothing you do with SQL. A query returns before-known columns, but you don't know them before. Two options: 1) Select single values and loop through your results with whatever programming language you are using (PHP, C#, ...). 2) Select all categories. Then build a query with one column per category. Run this query.

Comment: I need to do this with SQL not with another language.